# To prove the addition of the square of two ideals of a ring is the ring itself.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

> Let $I$ and $J$ are ideals of a commutative ring $R$ such that $I+J=R$. Then, is $I^2+J^2=R$ ?
>
> If not, then what are the minimum conditions needed to prove the result above?

Please help me to solve this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: May we assume that $R$ has an identity?

Comment: There is no word about identity in the question. @Randall

Comment: If the OP is using the category of commutative rings without necessarily a 1, then with $R = x \mathbb{Z}[x,y] + y \mathbb{Z}[x,y]$, $I = \langle x \rangle$, $J = \langle y \rangle$, clearly $x \notin I^2 + J^2$.

Comment: @DanielSchepler If you drop the $1$, there are examples with $I=J=R$.

Comment: Like $I=J=R=(x)$ as a rng contained in $\mathbb Z[x]$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer depends on what exactly your definition of a commutative ring is: whether it's required to have a multiplicative identity $1$ or not.

If $R$ does have a multiplicative identity $1$, then $1 = a + b$ for some $a \in I, b \in J$.  Then $1 = (a + b)^3 = (a + 3b) \cdot a^2 + (3a + b) \cdot b^2 \in I^2 + J^2$, so $I^2 + J^2$ is the entire ring.

If the definition of (commutative) ring you're using does not require a multiplicative identity $1$, then consider the subring of $\mathbb{Z}[x,y]$ generated by $x$ and $y$.  This is the subring of polynomials with a zero constant term.  Let $I := \langle x \rangle$ and $J := \langle y \rangle$.  Then $I^2 + J^2 = \langle x^2, y^2 \rangle$ is the ideal of polynomials such that the $x$, $y$, $xy$ coefficients are all zero.  In particular, $x \notin I^2 + J^2$, so $I^2 + J^2$ is not all of $R$.

Answer (score 3):

In this case, $1=a+b$ with $a\in I$, $b\in J$. Squaring gives
$1=a^2+2ab+b^2$. Well, $a^2+b^2\in I^2+J^2$, but that pesky $2ab$
stops us from concluding that $1\in I^2+J^2$. Can we get around this
problem somehow?

Comment: $(a+b)^3 \in I^2 + J^2$.

Comment: @DanielSchepler Or, perhaps more simply, $ab=a^2b+ab^2\in I^2+J^2$.  (I got the feeling Lord Shark was deliberately stopping as a hint for the student to continue, not really expecting any response. But on the other hand it isn't exactly clear what direction he expected to take, so listing possible routes doesn't seem like a bad idea...)